# Print PDF using iText 7 , .net

Tags: javascript, c#, printing, pdf-generation, itext7

Lately I was working on a requirement where a pdf needs to be generated and sent to printer ( option to select printer ) . I  am given option to choose any .net based tools. I choose iText 7 .
1. Was able to generate the pdf .
2.send to printer wasn't possible.

Earlier version had the support of `pdfaction.prntdlg` which is deprecated in latest. Could some help on this ?

Comment: For IText7, use the tag `itext7`, so could be reviewed appropiately...

Comment: Update : I let go the usage of Itext7 & made use of Media print , which made the quite easier.